# Accidentally deletion of classes from XCode 3.2.5 ...Please help me Please

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Accidentally my classes folder is deleted with reference from xcode(project). I try to recover them from trash but it was not present in trash. how ever I used svn for backup. but after check out the whole project when i try to run the project then it gives an error

> 2012-06-05 12:58:14.299 Lisnx[1285:207] Unknown class LisnxAppDelegate in Interface Builder file.
>   2012-06-05 12:58:14.301 Lisnx[1285:207] Unknown class LisnxViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   2012-06-05 12:58:14.304 Lisnx[1285:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewController.'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0119dbe9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012f25c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0119db21 -[NSException raise] + 17
>       3   Foundation                          0x000756cf _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
>       4   Foundation                          0x0007563d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
>       5   UIKit                               0x004f48d6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x011142cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
>       7   UIKit                               0x004f32ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
>       8   UIKit                               0x004f5081 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
>       9   UIKit                               0x002ff943 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
>       10  UIKit                               0x003004ca -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
>       11  UIKit                               0x0030adb2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
>       12  UIKit                               0x00303202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
>       13  UIKit                               0x00308732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
>       14  GraphicsServices                    0x01ad3a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x0117f064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x010df6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x010dc983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x010dc240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x010dc161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>       20  UIKit                               0x002fffa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
>       21  UIKit                               0x0030c42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
>       22  Lisnx                               0x00002528 main + 102
>       23  Lisnx                               0x000024b9 start + 53
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Please some body help me to way out from this problem. I will be thankful for him.

Comment: is LisnxAppDelegate  present in your code

Comment: yes its my  app deligate

Comment: and you can view it from xcode? it seems that you have the file but you are not referencing it on xcode so Interface Builder can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get-read of this exception easily. just going in project navigator right click on it then add file from existing source.adding all these classes and build it it successfully worked.

Comment: If one of the questions helped you, be sure to tick the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely just deleted the **Reference** of the Classes. Look in your project folder to make sure they are still there. If they are, just copy them back to your project browser.

As long as you didn't choose **Move to Trash** when you got the dialog then you are Okay. If you chose **Remove References**, then the files are still in your project folder on your computer, look there first before anything else.

**Remove References** only means that Xcode will remove the classes or files from your project and NOT delete them to the trash.

[image]