# can not find nib (xib) file

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my project there was a file named view controller.xib. I deleted a button from that and an window appear I select move to trash. And after deleting that control, I can't find my xib file. But my project is building successfully and running properly with that view. but I can't find that file in project and also from the project directory. How can i recover that xib file.
Need Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Clean and run. If you can't see it running with that xib, you have deleted it. Or it must be there in the project folder!!

Comment: It run properly, when i am running i can go to that view which actually physically does not exists. How is this possible?

Comment: You might have clicked remove references. Try searching it on spotlight

Comment: Are you close the project or not?

Comment: thanks everyone, @neonsamuel I restart my pc but didn't work.
Nina thanks for help

I found the xib file in my trash folder. I push it back and add to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you pressed delete button, your `file.xib` was selected from project, instead of deleting that control button, your Xib file was deleted, by clicking this dialog button.

[image: Delete confirmation dialog]

Now your file has been removed from your project. Look carefully what is being used instead that file.xib. may there is still another file under the same name, or you are using another file instead of this one.

As concerning the recovery of your file, you can have a look at these posts:

[Recovery deleted files from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8874174/593709)

[Accidentally deletion of classes from XCode 3.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10891635/593709)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Spotlight . Type the full name of the xib file with the extension . If you have not deleted it permanently and only clicked on "Remove Reference" only, then there is the possibility you'll find it. Else its gone , sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your project folder. you might have removed only its references, search for the file name and add it to your project .